# How do I catch all of these exceptions in python?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, try-catch

I am making a python program that takes in user input and uses `exec()` to execute it. Here is my code so far:

```
>>> while True:
...     var = raw_input('Enter the code: ')
...     exec(var)
...
```

This part works. However, I want to catch whenever the user enters input that raises an error, but I also want to print the error. This is what I did:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...             var = raw_input('Enter the code: ')
...             exec(var)
...     except * as e:
...             print e
...
```

This raises its own error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    except * as e:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this? Isn't this the correct syntax for excepting?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that that was valid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct syntax, here is your edited code:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...             var = raw_input('Enter the code: ')
...             exec(var)
...     except Exception as e:
...             print e
...
```

Instead of `except * as e`, use `except Exception as e`, because `*` as no value associated with it except in imports. However, I would suggest that you keep your `try: ... except: ...`'s as little as possible, so remove the `raw_input()` from the try, unless you really want to surround that too.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for using `*` is only used in imports. You want to use `Exception as e`, and then call `e` later as the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error, not an exception in your code.  The correct syntax for catching all exceptions is

```
try:
    <your code>
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

"Exception" is the root of the exception hierarchy, so it catches all program (but not system) errors. See [Section 8: Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) of the python tutorial.